# Git rebase interactive empty identity

Tags: git, rebase, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-config

I'm trying to perform a `git rebase -i some_commit` through Bash terminal on WSL to basically drop first commit on the list and apply remaining ones.

After the first *drop* of the commit in the stack of selected commits, rebase can not continue, complaining about empty commit author/email:

`fatal: empty identy name (for <my_pc_username@my_pc_name.my_domain_name) not allowed`

Double checked gitconfigs (repo specific & global) and user.name & user.email configurations are properly set, as expected, since I made those commits in this same computer.

Tried issuing the `git commit --author` but git keep complaining about the identity not set.

PS: Alternatively, tried a different approach:

- `git reset` to set the `HEAD` on the rebase commit
- manually `cherry-pick` each one of rebase remaining commits

...and worked out yet I still haven't found out which identity git does not *find* / *picks* and is not valid.

Since **error provided identity is not empty**, instead it **matches** the user/computer **info of my Windows machine**, and indeed, it is **not the same of my `user.name` and `user.email`** guess I might have some incompatibility between those two pairs.

Any idea, how to workaround the rebase and successfully complete it?

Comment: Fundamentally, `git rebase` works by copying commits (as if by `git cherry-pick`—some rebases, including `-i`, actually use cherry-pick). When it copies a commit, though, it tries to set the `--author` to the author of the original commit that is being copied. In this case it appears that this is the failing part. I don't have an off-hand fix or work-around and I suspect it depends on your Git version (since the rebase code changed relatively recently to make it go a lot faster on Windows).

Comment: Can you try to run git rebase with `--reset-author` flag? Only caveat: this will reset the author info of _all_ rebased commits.

Comment: And the error message should be "empty ident name", not "identy". At least I find the former in the Git code base, but not the latter.

Comment: Do you have any of the `GIT_AUTHOR_*` environment variables set/exported to an empty value?